# Accessing a variable across different scopes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope

```
var todoList = {
  todos: []


  displayTodos: function () {
     console.log(this.todos[i].todoText);
}

  addTodo: function (todoText) {
    this.todos.push({todoText: todoText});
}
}
```

This isn't the complete program, but my question is this:

In the displayTodos function, how am I able to access todoText (in the console log line)?

Shouldn't the todoText variable that's declared in the addToDo function be limited in scope to the function in which it's declared, addToDo?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations

Comment: Your code is not complete, this is not a way to declare an object literal. You are missing the `,` between different properties. Also, javascript is dynamic language and hence the property `this.todos[i].todoText` would be evaluated at run time. If you call the function `displayTodo` before calling the function `addTodo` it will give an `TypeError` error.

Comment: @Agalo is right, and it might still give an error after calling `addTodo`, depending on what `i` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with the ***context *** of a function. Not **scope**, but **context**.

#### Scope:

This relates to what variables are visible to a function.

Functions have access to their local variables (declared inside the body of their definitions *including* any argument parameters which get added as local variables) ***and*** any variables in the enclosing scope that they are called.

#### Context  (applies to OP question):

Has to do with ***how*** the function was called or ***what*** object it gets assigned to *at the time it is called/invoked*.  More specifically, it defines what the value of `this` resolves to in a function definition.

---

**An example**

Let's make the assumption that you are calling these methods as follows:

```
todoList.addTodo("some text");
todoList.addTodo("other text");
todoList.dispayTodo(1); // made this singular, see below for explanation
// logs out > "other text"
```

In the case above all three functions are called as methods of the object `todoList` and in turn, the `this` value inside of both will refer to the `todoList` object.

After pushing an object that contains a property `todoText` into `this.todos` array you'll have the following array:

```
[
  {todosText:"some text"},
  {todosText:"other text"}
]
```

And you can access each stay element by pushing in the correct index to `displayTodo`
(albeit with a slight modification to your code to accept the index as an argument)

```
var todoList = {
  ...
  displayTodo: function(i) {
    console.log(this.todos[i].todoText);
  }
}
```

Comment: The context isn't called "scope" at all.

Comment: @Bergi: thanks. I had to do a little reading so I could articulate my answer more clearly and have amended it accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can access todos because it is a property of the object you are creating, todoList.
2. todoText is not a variable, it's a property name for a new object you are creating and pushing to todos. Thus it can be used in any scope that has access to todos.

Technically, neither of the things you asked about is a variable. They are both properties of different objects that you are creating with the object literal syntax.